# Não consigo redimensionar o Popup em meu App

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

Baixei um projeto e tenho um popup funcionando. Fui fazer a mesma coisa no meu projeto e nada. Não dá nenhum erro, apenas o popup não sobe como deveria, ele ocupa toda área do mu App. Coloquei um botão no popup e aparece. Coloquei um Frame e dentro do Frame dois botões e pintei o Background do Frame em Azul e não aparece nada. Meu popup xaml e cs

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<pages:PopupPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:pages="clr-namespace:Rg.Plugins.Popup.Pages;assembly=Rg.Plugins.Popup"
             x:Class="Autorizador.Aprovar">    
    <StackLayout VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" Padding="0" Margin="0">
        <Frame Margin="30" Padding="10" BackgroundColor="AliceBlue">
            <Label HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" FontSize="Large" Text="Hello stilized popup!"></Label>
            <Button 
            HorizontalOptions="End"
            BackgroundColor="Gold"
            HeightRequest="30" 
            WidthRequest="80"
            Text="Gravar" 
            FontSize="9" 
            TextColor="Green" />
            <Button 
            HorizontalOptions="End"
            BackgroundColor="Gold"
            HeightRequest="30" 
            WidthRequest="80"
            Text="Feliz" 
            FontSize="9" 
            TextColor="Green" />
        </Frame>
    </StackLayout>
    <StackLayout VerticalOptions="End" HorizontalOptions="Fill">
        <Button 
            HorizontalOptions="End"
            BackgroundColor="Gold"
            HeightRequest="30" 
            WidthRequest="80"
            Text="Fechar" 
            Clicked="Fechar_OnClicked"
            FontSize="9" 
            TextColor="Green" />
    </StackLayout>
</pages:PopupPage>
```

e meu .cs

```
using Rg.Plugins.Popup.Extensions;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace Autorizador
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class Aprovar
    {
        public Aprovar()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //this.BackgroundColor = Color.White;
        }        

        private async void Fechar_OnClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            await base.Navigation.PopPopupAsync(true);
        }
    }
```

Veja abaixo um screenshot da tela do popup. O botão fechar está dentro do popup, mas o Frame não é mostrado, como se vê na imagem.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]